# Difficulty linking 4 SQL tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an SQL query I'm using currently which joins together 3 tables for a report. I need to append data from a fourth table to this.

Here is my current query, working fine:

```
SELECT `contact_id`,`account_id`,`last_name`,`first_name`,`name`,`phone_work`,`billing_address_street`,`billing_address_postalcode`,`phone_office`
FROM `crm`.`contacts`
LEFT JOIN `crm`.`accounts_contacts` ON `crm`.`contacts`.`id`=`crm`.`accounts_contacts`.`contact_id`
LEFT JOIN `crm`.`accounts` ON `crm`.`accounts_contacts`.`account_id`=`crm`.`accounts`.`id`
```

Here is my query I've tried to update, to bring in the additional field of email from a 4th table:

```
SELECT `contact_id`,`account_id`,`last_name`,`first_name`,`name`,`phone_work`,`billing_address_street`,`billing_address_postalcode`,`phone_office`,`email_address`
FROM `crm`.`contacts`
LEFT JOIN `crm`.`accounts_contacts` ON `crm`.`contacts`.`id`=`crm`.`accounts_contacts`.`contact_id`
LEFT JOIN `crm`.`accounts` ON `crm`.`accounts_contacts`.`account_id`=`crm`.`accounts`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `crm`.`email_addresses` ON `crm`.`accounts_contacts`.`contact_id`=`crm`.`email_addresses`.`id`
```

The query runs without an error, however the `email_address` column is filled with null values.

Here are the fields for each table:

```
`accounts_contacts`
id
contact_id
account_id

`email_addresses`
id
email_address
```

Anyone have any ideas where I'm going wrong? If I've missed out any necessary information, let me know and I'll edit it in.

---

Extra info:

It turned out that there was a missing link between my contacts and their email addresses. I created a test user to investigate this and this is what I found:

Firstly I found out my new user's contact id:

```
 `crm`.`contacts`.`id` = bf3259ec-65eb-1e65-efd1-51669e45cdb0
```

Then I found a table containing this id:

```
SELECT * FROM `crm`.`email_addr_bean_rel` WHERE bean_id = "bf3259ec-65eb-1e65-efd1-51669e45cdb0"
```

This returned an `email_address_id`

```
c3e14c9e-b6bc-b2d0-6dbf-51669e83bff4
```

This links to `crm`.`email_addresses`.`id`

Comment: The 4th join does not look correct, check the DDL of the table and what is the link between `email_addresses`  and `accounts_contacts` in other words what is the joining key. You are now using `email_addresses.id`. Usually it would be linked with the `contact id`

Comment: The id of the email address is a foreign key to which table?

Comment: @Alexander I'm currently trying to figure that out, with little success :( I thought it was the account id but I created a test account. I can find my test email but the id links to neither my contact id or my account id. Any ideas of ways i could search?

Answer (score 2):

Your query is easier to read if you use table aliases:

```
SELECT`contact_id`, `account_id`, `last_name`, `first_name`, `name`, `phone_work`,
      `billing_address_street`, `billing_address_postalcode`, `phone_office`, 
      `email_address`
FROM `crm`.`contacts` c LEFT JOIN
     `crm`.`accounts_contacts` ac
     ON c.`id` = ac.`contact_id` LEFT JOIN
     `crm`.`accounts` a
     ON ac.`account_id` = a.`id` LEFT JOIN
     `crm`.`email_addresses` ea
     ON ac.`contact_id` = ea.`id`
```

No `contact_id` values in `account_contacts` matches an `email_address.id`.  This could be:

- The latter table is empty.
- There are not matches.
- You are using the wrong columns for the join.

If I had to guess, it would be the last one.  I would expect a column called `email_address_id` somewhere, based on the naming conventions used for the rest of the tables.

Comment: I'm currently trying to find the link between contact/account and email address. Just set up a test account and searching for where my id's appear. It appears neither the contact id, nor the account id match an id in `email_addresses`. There must be a missing link somewhere but I can't find anything along the lines of `email_address_id`

Comment: Hi Gordon, I believe I have found the link but it may require joining yet another table. I'll update my question with this extra information.

Comment: I've solved this myself, but I will +1 you as your checklist of possible causes led me to finding the solution.